# $\sin x+\frac{\sin 3x}{3}+\frac{\sin 5x}{5}+...+\frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{2n-1}>0$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

> Let $x$ be a real number with $0<x<\pi$. Prove that for all natural
> numbers $n$, $$\sin x+\frac{\sin 3x}{3}+\frac{\sin
> 5x}{5}+...+\frac{\sin(2n-1)x}{2n-1}>0$$

By induction, assume that
$$F_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin(2k-1)x}{(2k-1)}$$

So, $F_1(x)=\sin x>0$ for $x \in (0,\pi).$ Thus the inequality is true for $n=1$.

Let $F_r(x)>0$ for $r=1,2,...,n-1$. We will deduce that $F_n(x)>0$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$. Suppose that $F_n(x_0)\leq 0$ for some $x_0\in(0,\pi)$ and that $F_n(x)$ attains its minimum at $x=x_0$. Hence $$\frac{d}{dx}[F_n(x)]_{x=x_0}=0$$.

$$\begin{align}\therefore F'_n(x_0)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cos((2k-1)x_0)=0
\\2\sin x_0F'_n(x_0)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}2\cos ((2k-1)x_0)\sin x_0
\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}[\sin(2kx_0)-sin((2k-2)x_0)]
\\&=\sin 2nx_0 \end{align}$$

$$F'_n(x_0)=\frac{\sin 2nx_0}{2 \sin x_0}=0$$
$$\sin 2nx_0=0$$
$$x_0 \in\{\frac{\pi}{2n},\frac{2\pi}{2n},\frac{3\pi}{2n},...,\frac{2n-1}{2n}\}$$

Each of these values will make $F_n(x_0)>0$, a contradiction. Therefore $F_n(x)>0$ for $x \in (0,\pi)$

How could we prove the proposed inequality by not using calculus?

Updated:
Realise there is a similar question asked but no solutions are proposed by not using calculus.
[Positivness of the sum of $\frac{\sin(2k-1)x}{2k-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710694/positivness-of-the-sum-of-frac-sin2k-1x2k-1?rq=1)

Comment: I don't think you are using mathematical induction properly in the proof.

Comment: try this,which might or might not work. First write  your sum as a difference of $$\sin x/1+\sin (2x)/2+... + \sin ((2n-1)x)/(2n-1)$$ and $$\sin (2x)/2+...+\sin ((2n-2)x)/(2n-2)$$Then sum each of those series by summation by parts, using $$\sin m\theta=\Delta\frac{\cos(m-1/2)\theta}{-2\cos (\theta /2)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to prove that   the function $g(x)=\sin((2n-1)x)$ is positive for $x\in]0.\pi[$. In fact, $g(x)$ has period $\dfrac{2\pi}{2n-1}$ so we have
$$0\lt x\lt \pi\Rightarrow \frac{0}{2n-1}\lt\frac{x}{2n-1}\lt\frac{\pi}{2n-1}=\frac12\cdot\frac{2\pi}{2n-1}$$ which means that $\dfrac{x}{2n-1}$ is in the first half of the period of $g(x)$ so the image for all such $x\in]0,\pi[$ is positive (because $x$ is in the first positive half of the period, the other part of it giving negative values of $g(x)=\sin((2n-1)x)$ till complete the whole of one period. Consequently for $0\lt x\lt\pi$ $$\sin(x)+\sin (3x)+\sin (5x)+...+\sin((2n-1)x)>0$$ and also the proposed sum is necessarily positive.

Comment: @lone student: Dear friend, your problem is certainly interesting and beautiful, but it is too difficult and an answer would certainly be worthy of a citable paper. Similar questions could be, for example, the open problems

 (1) is $e + \pi$ transcendental or algebraic?

 (2) We know that $e^{\pi}$ is transcendental, but is $\pi^e$ rational or irrational?

 There are a lot of such a questions.

Comment: @lone student.- You are welcome, dear friend. Regards.